# Отличие функций pandas.io от pandas

Tags: python, pandas, io

Объясните пожалуйста отличие `pandas.io`. от `pandas`?
Например, чем отличается функция `pandas.io.sql.read_sql()` от `pandas.read_sql()`. Что в итоге лучше использовать и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим [исходники](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) библиотеки `Pandas`. В частности, файл [`pandas/__init__.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/__init__.py):

```
from pandas.io.api import (
    ...
    # sql
    read_sql,
    ...
)
```

То есть на самом деле, когда вы обращаетесь к `pandas.read_sql`, то обращение идёт к `pandas.io.api.read_sql`. Хорошо, смотрим [`pandas/io/api.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/api.py):

```
from pandas.io.sql import (
    read_sql,
    read_sql_query,
    read_sql_table,
)
```

То есть это на самом деле обращение к `pandas.io.sql.read_sql`. А вот уже в [`pandas/io/sql.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/sql.py) действительно лежит метод `read_sql`:

```
def read_sql(
    sql,
    con,
...
```

Таким образом, нет никакой разницы, это обращение к одной и той же функции, только оформленное по-разному. Нет никакого смысла лазить вглубь субпакетов `pandas.io` и т.п. все нужные функции обычно вынесены "наружу", в корень пакета `pandas` и обращаться нужно обычно оттуда, как и написано в документации к `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql(...)
```